# 'URL Rewrite' option missing from IIS Manager (IIS7)

Tags: windows, iis-7, 64-bit

I just finished building up a new web server (2k8 x64) and have installed 'URL Rewrite' and 'Application Request Routing' but noticed that the 'URL Rewrite' option in IIS Manager is missing.

I messed around for a little while by re-installing both modules repeatedly and in different ways and then gave up.

I returned later, only to find that the icon had 'somehow' appeared.

Does anyone have any explanation for this ?

Thanks in advance.

Rabbie.

Answer (score 17):

The only time I've seen this happen is when you've opened IIS Manager, when you haven't  had the IISRewrite module/patch installed.

Then you close/open the manager and it appears.

(In fact, thats what happened to me, and how I found your question!)

Comment: And where do I get this patch?

Comment: There was no patch needed on Win8. I just reopened IIS Manager and now it shows!

Comment: Close/open did the trick. Even refresh and restarting server from manager didn't work, until I closed and opened it again.

Answer (score 15):

It may not be installed. http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite#additionalDownloads has download links for it on microsoft.com, and they list it being compatible w/ all versions IIS 7-10. Install that then restart IIS Manager. The x64 link does say AMD in the name even though it's for Intel as well, I've tested this install on an Intel 64 servers.

Comment: AMD64 is a typical moniker for x64. It's because the instruction set was originally released by AMD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Comment: When I try to [install the extension](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) the installer claims it is [already install](https://i.imgur.com/o81DIE7.png), and even after a reboot, the `URL Rewrite` feature is not shown anywhere in IIS 7.5.7600.16385.

Answer (score 2):

You can install it from [here](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/8/128E2E22-C1B9-44A4-BE2A-5859ED1D4592/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi) then restart your IIS.
It worked jsut fine for me.