# HTTP Error 500.19 - IIS 7.5 Error 0x8007000d

Tags: http, iis-7.5

While Transferring Website to new IIS 7.5 I am facing below error:

I am not sure whether it is programming error or server error

> Summary
>
> **HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error**
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
>
> **Detailed Error Information**
>   Module    IIS Web Core
>   Notification  Unknown
>   Handler   Not yet determined
>   Error Code    0x8007000d
>   Config Error
>   Config File   \?\E:\kunden\homepages\0\d442477881\www\web.config
>   Requested URL http://mcstech.co.uk:80/
>   Physical Path
>   Logon Method  Not yet determined
>   Logon User    Not yet determined
>   Failed Request Tracing Log Directory  faultRequestLogPath
>   Config Source
>      -1:
>       0:

This is the contents of my webconfig file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web">
            <section name="urlrewrites" type="ThunderMain.URLRewriter.Rewriter, ThunderMain.URLRewriter, Version=1.0.783.30976, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7a95f6f4820c8dc3"/>
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    </sectionGroup>
                    </sectionGroup>
                    </sectionGroup></configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=98.130.0.20;Initial Catalog=C283122_mcs;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=C283122_mcsweb;Password=Mcsweb100t"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <!--<add key="RTE.AjaxUploader.UploadSpeedKB" value="500"/>-->
        <!--<add key="RTE.ImageEditor.TempFolder" value="~/rtetemp"/>-->
        <add key="RichTextEditorTempPath  " value="~/rtetemp"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticcontent>
            <clientcache cachecontrolmaxage="150.00:00:00" cachecontrolmode="UseMaxAge">
            </clientcache></staticcontent>
        <modules>
            <remove name="ScriptModule"/><add name="UploadModule" type="RTE.UploadModule,RichTextEditor"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></modules>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
            <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </handlers>
            </system.webServer>

    <system.web>
        <sessionState cookieless="UseCookies" cookieName="Dont_delete_cookie" mode="InProc"/>
        <!--<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>-->
        <machineKey validationKey="ACCC9E972F97EC8FDEE6852A04F17354F47E574D8769E0DE65291BBC22898370CE31FE4117CD1715F0CD8A932A7C71D3A4971B8BD534557881756E573DA6AF18" decryptionKey="0253BD20700FC9BC9DABDAA663581BF14B455000C74CDA08D558E30839C95312" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
        <!--  <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />-->
        <!-- <customErrors mode="Off"/>-->
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="http://mcstech.co.uk/"/>

        <pages validateRequest="false">
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></controls></pages>

        <!--<httpModules>
      <add name="UploadModule" type="RTE.UploadModule,RichTextEditor"/>
    </httpModules>-->

        <urlrewrites>
            <rule>
                <url>/web-design-clients</url>
                <rewrite>web-design-clients.aspx</rewrite></rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/case-study/(.*)</url>
                <rewrite>/case-study.aspx?id=$1</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule><url>/case-studies</url>
                <rewrite>case-studies.aspx</rewrite></rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/internet-website-promotion-marketing</url>
                <rewrite>internet-website-promotion-marketing.aspx</rewrite></rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/flash-website-design</url>
                <rewrite>flash-website-design.aspx</rewrite></rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/ecommerce-site-design-development</url>
                <rewrite>ecommerce-site-design-development.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/custom-website-design</url>
                <rewrite>custom-website-design.aspx</rewrite></rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/website-design-process-steps</url>
                <rewrite>website-design-process-steps.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/sem-ppc-packages</url>
                <rewrite>sem-ppc-packages.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/home</url>
                <rewrite>Default.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/mcs-technologies</url>
                <rewrite>company.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/web-solutions</url>
                <rewrite>solutions.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/our-solutions/web-and-mobile-presence</url>
                <rewrite>/web-and-mobile-presence.aspx</rewrite></rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/our-solutions/online-branding</url>
                <rewrite>/online-branding.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/our-solutions/business-software-solutions</url>
                <rewrite>/business-software-solutions.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/our-solutions/online-sales-marketing</url>
                <rewrite>/online-sales-marketing.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/our-solutions/mobile-applications</url>
                <rewrite>/mobile-applications.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/web-design-services/web-design-development</url>
                <rewrite>/web-design-development.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/web-design-services/web-hosting</url>
                <rewrite>/web-hosting.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/web-design-services/mobile-app-development</url>
                <rewrite>/mobile-app-development.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/web-design-services/web-marketing</url>
                <rewrite>/web-marketing.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/web-design-services/seo</url>
                <rewrite>/seo.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/portfolio</url>
                <rewrite>portfolio.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/contact-mcs</url>
                <rewrite>contact_us.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/website-packages</url>
                <rewrite>website-packages.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/terms-conditions</url>
                <rewrite>terms-conditions.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/sitemap</url>
                <rewrite>sitemap.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/privacy-policy</url>
                <rewrite>privacy-policy.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/our-methodology/web-design-development</url>
                <rewrite>/m-web-design-development.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/our-methodology/web-marketing</url>
                <rewrite>/m-web-marketing.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/our-methodology/mobile-applications</url>
                <rewrite>/m-mobile-applications.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/our-expertise</url>
                <rewrite>our-expertise.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/careers</url>
                <rewrite>careers.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/request-for-proposal</url>
                <rewrite>request-for-proposal.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/testimonials</url>
                <rewrite>Testimonials.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/web-design-company</url>
                <rewrite>web-design-company.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/contact-us-confirmation</url>
                <rewrite>contact-us-confirmation.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/request-proposal-confirmation</url>
                <rewrite>request-proposal-confirmation.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/Captcha</url>
                <rewrite>Captcha.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
        </urlrewrites>
        <compilation debug="true">


            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Net, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/></assemblies></compilation>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/></httpModules></system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/></compiler>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/></compiler></compilers></system.codedom>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/></dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/></dependentAssembly></assemblyBinding></runtime></configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have the right framework version in the Application Pool?

Comment: I have same issue, as far as i searched this may happen due to permission issue for published folder or an invalid Web.config, but in your case the web.config seems to be valid. I'm sure that this is not an programming error, it should be an server error

Answer (score 117):

It seems you are using the url rewrite functionality. Please make sure that you have installed your rewrite software in the server other wise you may get this error.

To check whether URL rewrite is installed you can go to "IIS Home" and see if there is URL rewrite component in the list of components.

If you didn't find one then you can install the same using the below link:
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

You can also use the *Microsoft Web Platform Installer* and install the product **URL Rewrite**.

Comment: Which rewrite software should be installed? How to install it?

Comment: @splash27 URL rewrite is an Microsoft extension for IIS. i have added the link where you can get it. Hope this helps

Comment: It solved my trouble, and more...This link installer include as option php 7 cache for x64

Comment: should be the accepted answer. It's strange that URL Rewrite was preinstalled in IIS 10 in our server (Windows Server 2012R2).. but not in IIS 10 of our local machine (Windows 10)

Comment: Yes, if your `<system.webServer>` contains a `<rewrite>` section, then try temporarily deleting it. If that helps you overcome the error, you need to install.

Comment: Thank you for this!  This was driving me up the wall, because the [official help page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942055/http-error-500-19-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage) says that this error indicates a malformed XML element in the config file, but my config was well-formed XML.  They really ought to fix that.

Answer (score 40):

You probably have forgotten to install the Hosting Bundle for Windows.

From Microsoft web site download the ASP.NET Core/.NET Core: Hosting Bundle.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I had hosting bundle 3.1 installed, but still faced this error. I previously also had 2.1 installed, when the site was loading. so i installed 2.1 again and it started working. Can anyone help explain the behavior?

Comment: For us the web site was working. But suddenly stopped working and started to show the above error. It tured out .net core hosting bundle had gone bad. We did a repair and also installed url rewrite(though we did not have rewrite in our web.confg.) This solved it for us.

Comment: Link: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Comment: Thanks! that was my case.

Comment: This has solved it for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well that was easy, thanks !

Comment: @GaneshJadhav you can see this on the docs page "If the Hosting Bundle is installed before IIS, the bundle installation must be repaired. Run the Hosting Bundle installer again after installing IIS."

Comment: In my case I installed the SDK instead of the Hosting Bundle.  It looks like the Hosting Bundle includes the runtime but not vice versa.

Comment: On a new machine and IIS wouldnt read any config files on sites other than the default one ... the hosting bundle download site tells you that if the bundle was installed before IIS then you have to run the installer again and REPAIR.... and it worked ( after 2 days ) ... thanks!!!

Comment: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1
This is page with the latest one for net core 3.1 although it is no longer supported. Now the supporting from version net 6 up.

Comment: this worked for me, in my case I created an app that must be installed on a laptop for a client I had, and after installing IIS in the laptop and copying the build DLLs to the physical folder this error raised, but after installing the hosting bundle the problem was fixed. Hope this comment helps someone who did the same than me

Answer (score 29):

Try to install URL Rewrite by using Web Platform Installer. That fixed my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

HTTP Error 500.19 - IIS 7.5 Error 0x8007000d says about invalid element in your web.config. That's why IIS cannnot read this file for start your site. 
You can find probloem element by commenting some blocks and looking for type of error. Reasons of this error (500.19) may be different.

Answer (score 3):

Got this error on **IIS 10** (on windows 10) when tried to host **.net core 3.1** app.

In the **web.config** there is usually aspNetCore handler presented, which requires **AspNetCoreModuleV2** module. If you have got this in your web.config, verify that this module is installed.

To verify it, open IIS, select your site, in IIS section find Modules icon, open it, search for AspNetCoreModuleV2.

To install it: download from [ASP.NET Core Runtime 3.1.15](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1) a Hosting Bundle for Windows

Answer (score 2):

Removed directorybrowse line from web.config file and worked for me.

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <clear />
            <add value="Default.asp" />
            <add value="Default.htm" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  <!--<directorybrowse enabled="false"></directorybrowse>-->
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I applied answer from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39622034/769465) and it helped.

(installing rewrite url from this link: [x64 installer](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/8/128E2E22-C1B9-44A4-BE2A-5859ED1D4592/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi))

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had not installed **.Net Hosting Bundle** for Windows. Installing it solved my problem.

- Simply Go to the [Official Webpage of .Net Downloads](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet)
- Select your .Net Version.
- Search the **Windows | Hosting Bundle** under **Run apps - Runtime** having latest build for your version of .Net.
- Install the Hosting Bundle and now your published ASP .Net website will run on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, dotnet Core (3.1.23) was not installed correctly or somehow broken. I reinstalled it. The exception itself is a bit confusing, but correct. For me, even the "dotnet --info" command did not work before. After reinstallation issue  was gone.

Answer (score 0):

For DotNet Core, I was able to troubleshoot my issue by running the dotnet command as shown in the web.config file:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\<YourApp>.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
```

From the command prompt:

```
dotnet .\<YourApp>.dll  ...
```

In my case, when I ran the dotnet command directly, dotnet displayed the errors that were causing my specific issue to the command prompt. Seeing the error made it trivial to debug. The error was being hidden when running directly from the solution.

Comment: Hi, can you please elaborate how running the donet command helped you? when i run the command from the bin folder my asp.net mvc app runs fine but from the iis it shows HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 0x8007000d

Comment: @AdilH.Raza This has been a while ago, so I don't remember the exact issue I was having. But when I ran the project from the dotnet command line, it displayed the error to the shell. The error was being hidden when I ran from Visual Studio. So running from the shell allowed me to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed web hosting bundle from below link

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.1-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

Try repairing

Answer (score 0):

***For Me just worked repairing Asp.Net Hosting Bundle***
If not installed yet install latest from here -
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-6.0.2-windows-hosting-bundle-installer