Hosting Radzen Blazor web app on Windows Server 2022 datacenter
I have created a Blazor web app with Radzen Blazor studio.
I want to publish this web app on IIS (on Windows Server 2022 Datacenter), but I get an "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error":
Detailed Error Information:
Module             IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler            Not yet determined
Error Code         0x8007000d
Config Error       
Config File        \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TicketingSystemV03\web.config
Requested URL      http://localhost:80/TicketingSystemV03
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TicketingSystemV03
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User         Not yet determined

I tried to solve the problem by installing URL Rewrite and create a rule  like this link.
I did every step in this link but it's not working.
I tried to install all features in IIS Management inside My Windows - but that also is not working.

Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/q/13532447/18667225 ?

Hi @Ibrahim-Amer, The link Markus shared is useful, please try to install the Hosting Bundle for Windows. And tell us the good news.

Thank you @Jason Pan. it work's fine now

The .NET Core Hosting bundle allows ASP.NET Core apps to run with IIS.
For blazor app, we also need to install URL Rewrite Module.
